# what is the difference in output for float values?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a = 0.7;
    int c;
    c = a < 0.7;
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

Output printed is 1 though it is printing 0 for all cases except 0.7,7.7 and 0.9, why it is so??? Also it should be 0 because precedence of '<' operator is more than '=' operator

Comment: I think it is that time of the day again. The obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @ppeterka66 So 0.7 < 0.7 is supposed to be true? I haven't touched C in many years but that's one funny behaviour alright.

Comment: You write 0.7 but it can store only 0.699999 or 0.7000001 in a float. Because it can not be exactly represented.

Comment: Sure but wouldn't you think that 0.7 should always be stored the same way and not randomly? That's what I mean by funny.

Comment: Take a deep breath, think, remove additional question marks and write a decent question which you could also present your teacher. Your current question is basically worthless: for example "except 0.7, 7.7"? Where do you actually use `0.7`? Other than that, ppeterka's link will contain the answer. Probably.

Comment: @S_F I had the same question myself some weeks back, however I cannot find it now, but there was a question regarding a similar issue, and it turned out, that there are some undefined behavior surrounding the equality of floating point numbers. In that particular question, the same number was `printf`ed twice, and one would print 99, the other time 100... It was the weirdest thing I saw. (By the way, I posted the link to be more of a warning, that floating point numbers aren't as trivial as they seem)

Comment: @ppeterka66 I just checked in C# and wow, it gives the same weird result. I thought it would somehow be smarter about it. I guess you learn new things every day. Thanks for that link, I'm sure it will become very useful if I stumble upon this weirdness by chance ever again.

Comment: @S_F also check n.m.'s answer, it contains the bleeding obvious cause to why this happens - without any of the undefined behavior I was referring to, but the differnce between the precision of the data types in the condition...

Comment: And it's `int main`, not `void main` in C.

Answer (score 13):

0.7 cannot be represented exactly as a `float` value, so `a` stores some approximation of it. The gotcha here is that the literal 0.7 has type `double`, so a more precise approximation of 0.7 is used to represent it. That approximation may differ from the less precise one in either direction.

To fix, use a `double` variable, or a `float` literal `0.7f`.

Answer (score 0):

Your basically dealing with the fact that `0.1` is a repeating decimal in binary.  So things that *look* nice and clean as literals (i.e. `0.7`) can't be represented exactly.  Coupled with this you're mixing types since the literal `0.7` is a `double`.